# Exclude auto-generated image sizes in WordPress uploads folder with gitignore

Tags: wordpress, git, gitignore

I have a directory structure similar to [bedrock](https://github.com/roots/bedrock). So WordPress in its own subdirectory `wp/` and the stuff that normally goes into wp-content is in `app/`. I want to exclude all directories in `app/` BUT `uploads/`.

But inside `uploads/` itself I want to exclude every image that was automatically generated by WordPress. So every file that follows the pattern `$original_image_name-$widthx$height.$ext`.

I tried the different solutions from all the already asked questions there are and my current (still not working) **.gitignore** looks like this now:

**.gitignore**

```
# WordPress
public/wp/
public/app/*
!public/app/uploads
public/app/uploads/*-*x*.* # auto-generated sizes
```

When checking `git status public/app/uploads/` it still shows the auto-generated files as `Untracked files` along with the other images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error actually just was that I added the `#` comment in the same line as the pattern..

So what I got now is

**.gitignore**

```
public/wp/
public/app/*
!public/app/uploads/
public/app/uploads/*-*x*.*
```